Acer Swift 3 SF314-59 намертво зависает во время игры и нагревается как атомный реактор?
Есть ноут (не мой) Acer Swift 3 SF314-59. Вообще ужасная машина, но суть не в том. Он греется как атомный реактор во время игры в не требовательную игру, что-то типа CS 1.6 либо во время работы в Visual Studio. Купил подставку с кулерами (8 штук, дорогая), но ничего не помогло.
Сервисный центр ничего не помог, сказали, что ноут такой и всё
Видел на просторах интернета драйверы для кулеров, что бы не так грелся, но не знаю, стоит ли.
Плюс, во время игры, через некоторое время намертво зависает. Скорее всего из-за перегрева, т.к. верхняя часть клавиатуры (Часть ряда с цифрами и qwerty) нереально сильно греется, что невозможно держать пальцы на клавишах.
Помогут ли тут какие-то драйвера, или проще реально его выкинуть (Или раздолбить об стенку), или всё-таки можно что-то сделать?

Я на своём ноуте в настройках ограничил производительность процессора значением 99%. Так часто рекомендуют делать. В результате у него не включается турбобуст. С тех пор он не шумит, не греется. Правда, это не избавит от нагрева видюхи.

Вообще конечно смешно использовать "пишущую машинку" для игр и возмущаться, что она перегревается при этом. Мой Huaway MateBook D14 точно такой же (хотя проц в нём и помощнее вроде) - для работы, сайтов и т.д. он вполне годен, а как только игру какую-то запускаешь, то греется так, что страшно за него. Ну, не предназначены такие ноуты для игр, всё что вы можете делать - это лечить симптомы.

@CrazyElf, да, но я не думал что оно будет греться от CS 1.6 )

куллеры, пасты и подставки не избавляют от нагрева хотя бы потому что они лишь отводят тепло а не прекращают его генерацию. чтоб снизить нагрев, надо снизить нагрузку. первым делом почистите фон(лишние процессы, службы, задачи и вот это всё) повыкидывайте из автозапуска всё то чем пользуетесь примерно никогда. я не думал что оно будет греться от CS 1.6 чем старее игра, тем старее используемые в ней технологии, а чем они старее, тем как правило: 1 хуже оптимизированы. 2 выше риск, что единственный способ их использовать - эмуляция(нагрузка х2 х3..). а CS 1.6 откуда то из времен DirectX 8/9...

@puffleeck, бросил винду, настроил всё, удалил не нужные дефолтные программы, заново тестировал нагрузку и всё то самое

@Faraday Я свою любимую Orcs Must Die 2 на своём запускал, думал он расплавится нафик )  При том, что старенький десктоп с простенькой видюхой под ней же не особо вроде и напрягался.

@Faraday, как вариант можно лишних потребителей поотрубать. wifi, оптический привод если есть, второй накопитель(экономия спичек конечно, но все таки). если в диспетчере нагрузка ЦП высокая(хотя бы во время игры) можно отключить всякие турбо бусты(если еще не отключены по какой то причине...), отключение гипертрейдинга вроде вкусное(10 - 20% потребления цп может съэкономить). а вообще... попробуй поставить виртуалку с той виндой, которая была популярна во времена кс 1.6 и запусти уже на ней. либо в ярлыке кс"ки включи режим совместимости

@puffleeck С виртуалкой же ещё хуже будет. Это ещё лишняя нагрузка )

@CrazyElf так то оно так, но вроде не совсем... если железо хоста, ОС и виртуализатор свежие, то не обязательно будет именно хуже. встроенную в ЦП виртуализацию кмк не просто так пиарят, надо проверять на практике ))

Кратко: Можно
В целом на температуру влияет немало факторов, и её можно уменьшить по разному:

убрать ненужные фоновые нагрузки
почистить ноутбук от пыли и заменить термопасту
переустановить винду

Для решения проблемы нужно чуть больше информации. Что показывает диспетчер задач во время нагреваний? Что загружено и какие температуры. Так-же вопрос, что уже пытались сделать люди в сервисном центре, это может помочь сузить варианты.

В сервисном центре сделали всё то самое, но сказали прямо, что это не поможет сильно. Почему? Потому что это маленький ноутбук (Можете загуглить) и процессором Intel Core i3-1115G4 3.00 GHz, и там просто не хватает охлаждения. Замена термопасты не помогла. Во время игры греется градусов 80

Тогда скажу прямо. 80 градусов в целом терпимая температура особенно для ноутбуков. Во вторых это ноутбук не для игор, и больше подходит как печатная машинка или для просмотра видео. Это как на мотоблоке пытатся ехать по скоростной трасе) (Простите за аналогию)
PS: И пожалуйста не разбивайте его об стену

Пробуйте установить программы типа SpeedFan, поднимите обороты вентиляторов до 100%.

Не знаю стоит ли

Конечно стоит в вашем случае, на ноутбуках не так много вариантов как понизить температуру.
К тому же дополню чужой ответ, в настройках электропитания в панели управления нужно попробовать ограничить производительность процессора до 99%. Если не поможет - пробовать опускать ещё ниже, да, мощность будет потеряна, но это всяко лучше зависаний намертво. В связке с увеличением оборотов кулера все должно придти к норме.
Ещё есть максимально колхозный вариант, который лично мне очень сильно давно помог - взять вентилятор, который можно к чему-то подключить(usb, к розетке), и поток воздуха направить в трубу формы конуса, а узкую ее сторону воткнуть в какую-нибудь щель в ноутбуке кроме тех щелей, из которых воздух выходит. Это ужасно неудобно и ноутбук превращается буквально в пылесос, но лично мне это сбросило около 12 градусов на процессоре. Но это конечно уже прям самые крайние меры, если после всех способов осталось лишь

Или раздолбить об стенку


Как вариант, что делать - это решать проблему с охладом. Можешь в биосе подредактировать кривую для внутренних кулеров, либо через утилиту. Ну и выяснить, что так нагружает систему, как ведёт себя ноут в простое. Просто помониторить диспетчер задач и смотреть какие процессы нагружают больше всего тот компонент, который вызывает сильный нагрев. Почитал про ваш ноут, не такой уж он и мотоблок на скоростной трассе, видел и похуже. Такие игры, как cs 1.6 он должен спокойно проглатывать, она у меня спокойно шла на двухядерном атлоне со встроенной графикой. Далее можно понижать частоты проца или как уже сказали ограничить энергопотребление для него (если греется именно проц). Еще конечно можно термопасту поменять на нормальную, не кпт-8 с алика, которую обычно и мажут в сервисах, а отвалить за нормальную рублей 800-1200 с хорошей теплоотдачей, для меня эта разница составляла градусов 5-10 по сравнению с более дешевой.

Спасибо за совет. В сервисном выбирали саму дорогую и хорошую термуху, но что-то толку от неё не особо. Возможно проблема с охлаждением, либо наоборот, с тем, что какой-то компонент греется чрезмерно сильно. До сервисного он грелся 80 градусов в ПРОСТОЕ. Сейчас ситуация немного лучше, но проблема не решена

Да, у меня когда-то давно CS 1.6 шла на интегрированной видюхе на 512 Мб, а тут 8 Гб... Странная вещица...
